# Print values of varriable stored in MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, string, mysqli, echo

I have varriable stored in a MySql Database and want to echo the string and the varriable in it. The varriable should give the values set in the php code page.

A varriable `$MyVarr` is stored in db as `"This is $MyVarr"` and then echoed in a string.

```
$MyString = $rw['MyStoredVarr'];
echo $MyString;
```

However this is not returning the values of `$MyVarr`, it returns the whole string

```
"This is $MyVarr"
```

How do I get this to work out.

EDIT::

I have tried to do this, store `"This is {$MyVarr}"` in the DB but still can't get it to parse the variable.

Comment: This is a security breach waiting to happen.

Comment: You stored the *string* *"This is $MyVarr"*, you get the same back. There's hardly any sane way to have "$MyVarr" evaluate to a variable value.

Comment: You mean its not a good practice to store variables in a db

Comment: Why do you want a variable in database? what problem you are trying to solve this way?

Answer (score 0):

Just because a string coming from somewhere contains a dollar followed by some name does not mean it's going to be substituted by a variable value any chance it gets. That'd be chaos! Some user types "$foo" into your web form, the string passes through your system and at the end it's been substituted by a variable value? No, that's a disaster waiting to happen.

Variable substitution only happens when with *string literals written in source code*, i.e.:

```
$foo = 42;
$bar = "Hi, I'm $foo";
```

It does not happen here:

```
$foo = 42;
$bar = $_POST['bar'];  // Hi, I'm $foo
```

or anywhere else.

If you have variable parts in a string stored in a database, you need to replace those part manually. E.g.:

```
$string = getFromDatabase(); // e.g.: "Hi, I'm %foo%"
$string = str_replace('%foo%', 42, $string);
```

Comment: thanks for that insight, I Will make sure never to do that. I guess I will try out @rohan-kumar Method too its as good as yours

Comment: What he suggests is very different, since he's substituting the variable *before* storing the result in the database.